# Get frame.size of SSCollectionViewItem

Tags: iphone, ios, sstoolkit

I am using SSToolkit/SSCollectionView and I have a custom SSCollectionViewItem but I am having a hard time getting the frame size for that view which was set by the SSCollectionView Delegate:

```
- (CGSize)collectionView:(SSCollectionView *)aCollectionView itemSizeForSection:(NSUInteger)section {
return CGSizeMake(280.0f, 280.0f);
}
```

Here is the item being initalizes:

```
#pragma mark - Initializer

- (id)initWithReuseIdentifier:(NSString *)aReuseIdentifier {
    if ((self = [super initWithStyle:SSCollectionViewItemStyleImage reuseIdentifier:aReuseIdentifier])) {
        if([aReuseIdentifier isEqualToString:@"featuredIdentifier"]) {
            NSLog(@"Frame: %f", self.frame.size.width);
            return self;
        } else {
            self.imageView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.95f alpha:1.0f];
            return self;
        }

        self.imageView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.95f alpha:1.0f];
    }
    return self;
}
```

`NSLog(@"FRAME Width:%f", self.frame.size.width);` always returns a 0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the expected behavior. All collection view items are always initialized with CGRectZero since they could be reused in a section with different item sizes.

SSCollectionView automatically sizes the items right before they are displayed. You should implement `layoutSubviews` if you need to do layout based on the item's size.

Also, it looks like you are trying to do different drawing based on the identifier. I highly recommend you make a different class for each identifier to keep things clean and understandable.

Answer (score 1):

Across most (all?) Cocoa frameworks, frames are not set until sometime later, when the view will come on screen. If you are inside a view, this can be as late as `willMoveToWindow`, I think. In most cases, view geometry should be set by the ViewController during `viewWillLayoutSubviews` or similar, and subviews can (should) be setup to use proper "struts and springs" (i.e. `autoresizingMask`). See various parts of the [UIView reference page](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html).

Comment: In this case, I would also recommend `collectionView:willDisplayItem:atIndexPath:`. Personally, I prefer `willMoveToSuperview:` instead of the window variant as well.

Comment: @SamSoffes, I'm not confident the geometry is ready when `willMoveToSuperview` is called; am I wrong? I like your suggestion above of `layoutSubviews`; slipped my mind.